# How to echo both the name and the value in an associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, post, get, associative

I have the following code to find all the values of an array and echo them...

```
foreach($_POST as $result) {
     echo $result;
}
```

But I want to be able to find the name of the array item too such as...

```
foreach($_POST as $result) {
     echo "The value of $thing is $result";
}
```

Does this make any sense? Sorry

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: Please take a look at the [documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) before heading to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will put the array keys in `$key` and value in `$value` variables.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
   echo "The value of $key is $value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the array key:

```
foreach($_POST as $thing => $result) {
     echo "The value of $thing is $result";
}
```

See the [PHP foreach docs](http://www.php.net//manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)